# Code block not getting executed

Tags: php

I was trying to make a little report management system recently. Everything was going well till I encountered this weird problem. Since the code contains lots of html, I'll only include the important parts.

Basically this is a login page. I am storing the information in SESSION variable.

When the username and pass doesn't match, the error message is given to this below function for further processing.

Edit: Every page in my project includes a config.php with following contents

```
// Start of config.php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

// ********************* Database Config **********************//
$dbHost = "localhost";          // MySQL host
$dbUser = "";   // MySQL username
$dbPass = "";   // MySQL password
$dbDatabase = "";  // MySQL main database name
```

A part of login.php is shown below.

```
//START OF PHP CODE//
include("config.php");

    function gotError($msg)
    {
        $_SESSION['err'] = $msg;
        header("Location: login.php");
        die();
    }

//CODE FOR EVALUATION OF DATA//

// END OF THE PHP CODE & BELOW THE HTML WILL START //
```

And on the same page, below the starting php code, there is the html code of page. Between the html, there are some bits of php code for using the data set above.

```
----------- SOME HTML CODE HERE----
         <?php

         if(isset($_SESSION['err']))
         {
         $html.= "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         $html.= '$.alert("'.$_SESSION['err'].'");';
         $html.= "</script>";
         print $html;
         }
        ?>
----------------- SOME HTML CODE HERE--------
```

Now here's the weird behavior comes in. The page post the login data to itself & if error occurs, the error is set in session variable { $_SESSION['err'] } and then redirected to itself again which displays a jquery message box if $_SESSION[ 'err' ] is not empty.

The above code doesn't work in the original form, however, if I do like code shown below, the code works. I mean the whole code including the conditional components which didn't worked previously. As soon as I remove that particular line, the conditional evaluation doesn't work.

```
     <?php
     print($_SESSION['err']);

     if(isset($_SESSION['err']))
     {
     $html.= "<script type='text/javascript'>";
     $html.= '$.alert("'.$_SESSION['err'].'");';
     $html.= "</script>";
     print $html;
     }
    ?>
```

Does anyone have a clue about this? I am using PHP Version 5.3.8.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the start of your script?

Comment: I've added the additional information. The problem is not that session variable is not getting set, but its just evaluating the if condition when I print something above it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `session_start()` to actually enable the session? Without that, you'll just be wasting your time. Unless you start the session, php will **NOT** save any data your write to `$_SESSION`, not will it load any data that was previously saved elsewhere.

Comment: Obviously I am calling that. Every page includes the config file which has the session_start(). 

I didn't included that info because I thought it was obvious when I've written that its working and showing the content of session variable when I am adding that print statement but I've added that information now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. Comes out that changing the position of the php script between the HTML from head to body did the trick.